Regarding the definition of unbiasedness and connections to MSE
My impression is that the definition of an unbiased estimator is always made for a single parameter. Is there a reason that the definition cannot be extended for a vector of parameters? For example, is there any reason that we do not say that $(\overline{X}, S^2)^T$ is an unbiased estimator for $(\mu, \sigma^2)$? I cannot see any reason not to do so. It seems that you can have a vector version of bias defined: $\text{bias}(\underline{\hat{\theta_n}})=E(\underline{\hat{\theta_n}})-\underline\theta$ and facts such as the bias-variance decomposition for MSE should hold. Am I missing something here?

Since the expectation of a vector of parameters is well defined, there is no reason not to talk about the bias of such estimators.  A vector valued bias makes sense then, and can be interpreted as the element wise bias.

@DemetriPananos - That is what I thought. But I was worried that it was not done this way because some well known fact will fail if we did this. So it sounds like your answer is we can, but we don't seem to?

It isn't that we don't seem to; we do talk about the bias of vector valued parameters.  Perhaps you haven't come across this because it is conceptually simpler to talk about the bias in a single parameter.  I would assume this is the case since understanding this concept is a requisite for understanding bias in the vector valued case.

@DemetriPananos - Thank you for the clarification. Could you please provide me with a reference? Most texts I found either work with a scalar or speak about the issue vaguely. If you post the reference as an answer, I will go ahead and accept it as it would answer my question.

With respect to vector valued MSE in particular, you could start by reading this section of the Wikipedia entry for Bias of an estimator, in which the MSE is generalized in the vector valued case to be a function of the trace of the covariance matrix and the squared norm of the bias
$$ \operatorname{MSE}(\hat{\theta})=\operatorname{trace}(\operatorname{Cov}(\hat{\theta}))+\|\operatorname{Bias}(\hat{\theta}, \theta)\|^2 $$
This entry references Taboga's 2010 lectures on mathematical statistics.  I personally gave no experience with these lectures.  There is also this answer on math stack exchange which, in a hand waving fashion, explains that one can obtain this identity with some matrix algebra.
References

Taboga, Marco (2010). "Lectures on probability theory and mathematical statistics"

